# How to load a property of an XML-file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I want to load the `highscore` of an XML file and spend the first place in a label. How do I manage to read the first entry and spend its value?

```
public class Highscore_obj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}


class Highscore
{
    public Highscore_obj[] Score_array = new Highscore_obj[4];

    public void LoadXmL(string path)
    {
        XmlDocument XML = new XmlDocument();
        using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            XML.Load(s);
        }

        Score_array[0].Name = "Alex";
        Score_array[0].Score = 1000;

        Score_array[1].Name = "Chris";
        Score_array[1].Score = 940;

        Score_array[2].Name = "Stefan";
        Score_array[2].Score = 700;

        XmlNodeList Highscores = XML.ChildNodes;

    }
```

When I start my game the `Highscore` of Alex must be visible in the label.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an Array I would rather suggest using a List. Then you can use Linq to query your list and sort by score descending. I would also rather use serialization and deserialization to load and store your List to and from XML.

The code below illustrates this and should get you on the right track.

```
    internal List<Highscore> Highscores { get; set; }

    public void LoadXmL(string path)
    {
        List<Highscore> highscores = null;

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Highscore>));

        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
        {
            highscores = (List<Highscore>)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        if (highscores == null)
        {
            highscores = new List<Highscore>
            {
                new Highscore{ Name = "Alex", Score = 1000 },
                new Highscore{ Name = "Chris", Score = 940 },
                new Highscore{ Name = "Stefan", Score = 700 },
            };
        }

    }

    public class Highscore
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
    }

    public Highscore GetHighest()
    {
        return Highscores.OrderByDescending(o => o.Score).First();
    }
```